# What type of liver is richest in Vitamin D?

Tags: nutrition, healthy-cooking, vitamin-d, meat, livestock

My test reports show that my Vitamin D - 25H (Hydroxyvitamin D) is **6.16 ng/ml** whereas the normal range is **30 - 100 ng/ml**.

So, I read a few articles (e.g. [medicinenet](http://www.medicinenet.com/vitamin_d_deficiency/article.htm), [patient.info](https://patient.info/in/health/vitamin-d-deficiency-including-osteomalacia-and-rickets-leaflet)) on the internet and they said that liver is a good source of Vitamin D.

> So, which liver i.e. chicken, lamb, beef etc is best for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older the animal, the greater the amount of vitamin D stored in the liver. While liver is a *somewhat* good source of vitamin D, it's also **very** high in vitamin A. A person eating liver  more often than once or twice a week could possibly overload on vitamin A. Especially in the amount youd need to correct a vitamin D deficiency. Vitamin A is toxic in larger amounts.

Just one serving of 100 grams of beef liver contains 26,000 IU of vitamin A. 100 grams is roughly the size of a woman's palm. The US Institute of Medicine gives an upper limit of 3,000 IU of vitamin A per day. Vitamin D content in beef liver, however, is only 49 IU. The USDA Nutrient Database doesn't even list vitamin D in chicken or lamb liver.

Why not take vitamin D tablets? They're available as D3 (cholecalciferol) and it's converted to calcitriol, the active metabolive used in the body. It's inexpensive and the dose can be better controlled than by eating liver. Your doctor would be best suggesting how much D to take.

Comment: Just the obligatory reminder to include references when you get up tomorrow! Sorry about being so strict about it, this is site-policy.